# Spring WebClient async callback not called when http server response 404

Tags: spring, webclient

A problem I encountered is as titled, and the code is below:

```
Mono<Account> accountMono = client.get()
    .uri("accounturl")
    .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    .exchange()
    .flatMap(response -> {
                            if (response.statusCode().equals(HttpStatus.OK)) {
                              return response.bodyToMono(Account.class);
                            } else { 
                              return Mono.empty();
                            }
                          });

accountMono.subscribe(result -> callback(result));
```

```

**`Server response 404`**. I try to create an empty Account, but the `callback()` is not called. It looks like the empty `Mono` is not emitted.

Answer (score 1):

> Server response 404, I try to create a empty Account

You're not creating an empty `Account`. You're returning an empty `Mono`, i.e. a `Mono` that will never emit anything.

If you want to return a Mono which emits an empty Account, then you need

```
return Mono.just(new Account());
```

Comment: Another question can I ask your suggestion. I want to expose 404 to upper layer app to know the account is not found instead of return a Account object. Can I use ClientResponse as reply to callback and check there? Thanks.

Comment: I don't have the required experience with reactive apps to suggest the best solution